# Automated Slideshow Creator

Tags: php, linux, slideshow

I am looking for a simple slideshow creator. I have a group of images that i need to pull from a server and then convert them to a slideshow with transitions like the kenburns effect, fade and zoom. The output format does not matter, for example it can be flash, mp4, mpeg, .mov, anything. These slideshows will then be uploaded to Youtube with there API. I have tried the linux slideshow maker, PHP ming, and a few others however i can not come close to the quality of Windows Movie Maker or Apple's slideshow creator.

This process has to be automated for thousands if not millions of slideshows with the amount of pictures in each slideshow ranging from 3 to 30. Windows no longer provides a way to use movie maker from the command line.

Any options/opinions...has anyone been in a similar situation, what software did you use.

Comment: Not sure this belongs in StackOverflow, not a programmer's question. Your tags are "php" and "linux" but you don't ask anything about PHP and you seem to be running Windows and not linux

Answer (score 1):

Wowslider does a pretty good job. 
http://wowslider.com/

I'd check them out

Comment: He was looking for a backend solution to generate a real video output which he will upload to youtube. Wowslider is just a js/css animation.